# Apply Excel VBA macro to all highlighted cells

Tags: vba, excel

Thank you in advance, I am very new to excel VBA. This question may be very elementary, but I haven't found the answer in an extensive search. I originally recorded this macro and tweaked it with stuff I've found online. This macro works  if you apply to one cell at a time (or if you drag across multiple rows, will work on the row of the top-left-most cell). Is there a way I can further tweak it to get my macro to apply the changes to the rows of all selected cells so that the user can make changes to rows in bulk?

```
Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":I" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5"
Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":I" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .FontStyle = "Regular"
    .Size = 11
    .Strikethrough = True
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With
Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're after?

```
'Instead of this:
'Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":I" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
'Do this:
With Application.Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Range("A:I")).Interior
'The range at hand is now all the cells in the rows of the selection, 
'  but limited to columns A:I.
'Notice we haven't actually modified the selection
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
'Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).FormulaR1C1 = "5"
Application.Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Range("A:A")).FormulaR1C1 = "5"
'Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":I" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
With Application.Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Range("B:I")).Font
    .Name = "Calibri"
    .FontStyle = "Regular"
    .Size = 11
    .Strikethrough = True
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
End With
Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Select
```

Note: It is not necessary to `.SELECT` a range and then do `something`. You can usually just apply `something` to the range. What you're starting with is typical for macro recorder code, just know there is a cleaner way.

Comment: Yes, this does exactly what I want it to. Thank you for the help! Is there a way I can get the macro to leave the user with the same cells selected as before they ran the macro? Like if they Ctrl+click multiple cells and then apply this formatting macro to the cells, their same cells are selected afterward? Thanks!

Comment: Sure -- just comment out the very last line so it looks like `'Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row).Select`.